# Get an array from a curl response

Tags: arrays, api, curl, printing, echo

I am using curl this way:

```
$key='e32b9123419e4b68fd71a1';
$url='http://api-product.skimlinks.com/categories?key='.$key.'&format=xml';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
```

This prints me onto the screen the curl execution. I would need not to print it but to have it stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this curl option, it will return you the response into the variable $result;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```